Web browsers window sizes are smaller than my Windows 10 display resolution
I have Windows 10 and 4 web browsers installed.
Browsers Zoom set to 100%, OS Scale and Layout 100% too, and LogPixels Key in Regedit is 60 Hexadecimal (96 Decimal).
Whatever is my display resolution (my default is 1920x1080), the websites' elements width on all browsers appear around 15-20% smaller (1600 when resolution is 1920 and so on whatever the resolution). It appear like I'm using OS scaling while I'm not ( note: Only the web browsers scaled because when I use print screen and paste in graphic program the size is 1920).
I checked many articles but couldn't find anything that helped me.
Note: When I switch to Windows 7 installed on same PC I find everything works great.
UPDATE
I'm attaching two screens to make it clear how the screen is 1920 while the web element is 1585 pixel on windows 10 while it's 1903 pixel on windows 7 without using the windows 10 scaling or browser zooming in.



Many websites limit their display, but this is done from the website and not by Windows. It's possible that under Windows 10 the browser works differently (or better).

Smaller than what? If at all possible, please provide a screenshot illustrating the issue. (This is a corrected repost of my earlier comment.)

@DanielB
I need the browser window and layout appear as the same or close to 1920 as on my Windows 7 (1903) ... No the websites I tested not limiting the  or using viewport or anything that limit the width because I tested them too including this website on both OS.

Please do provide a concrete example so we can investigate. With a screenshot of what you see, if possible. Otherwise I don't see any way to answer this.

@harrymc I'm attaching two screens to make it clear how the screen is 1920 while the web element is 1585 pixel on windows 10 while it's 1903 pixel on windows 7 without using the windows 10 scaling or browser zooming in.

@DanielB thank you for your support. I did and updated the post :)

For the SU site it's the same on my computer - the website is doing it. Look in the Computed attributes of HTML element <div class="container"...>. For me I see "max-width: 1264px" which comes from CSS file primary.css. It's possible that the Windows 7 browser is different, and it's also possible that the website itself has CSS that's conditional on your browser or computer attributes.

@harrymc I'm a developer and container css limitation is not the issue, I'm pointing with the mouse to body tag and that wont appear until you have large screen.

Every HTML element can have a width attribute, not only the body. Elements that are not 100% wide may leave an empty area inside their container.

Okay so by now we have established that your browser on Windows 10 is behaving as expected. Websites often have a maximum width defined one way or the other. For comparison, please provide a screenshot of what you see on Windows 7 so we can analyze the difference.
